# Is there a way to run and execute Java files using HTTP from another PC?

Tags: java, http, jar

I have installed Java and developed on my laptop. Now I want to access those files from my PC using HTTP. Both machines are on the same network. I'd like to access the page as we do in PHP:

> http:// and the path

How can I do it? I can see the files using this url: `file://machine-name/login.html`, but it's not opening in HTTP, replacing file from the url. Please help

Comment: are you trying to run your java program from another pc or just get the files to your own pc ?

Comment: try to work thru [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld) brief tutorial and a lot of things will get clearer

Comment: Somehow, it is not clear (to me) from your question *what* you have developed, and *what* you want to access. I see that a recent edit included the [web-development] tag but is this what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike PHP, in Java you can serve only JSP or Servlets. You will need to have an Application Server - like Tomcat, to deploy your web components. There are many different ways how you can package your web components. Typically all files (JSP, Servlets, Classes) etc. are packaged in a 'war' file. Thiw war file can be deployed to any Java compliant application servers.

Try this URL - [Simple Tomcat application](http://keyboardsamurais.de/2004/01/15/tomcat_tutorial_helloworld_for_complete_fools_-_english/)

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Sreehari.

Comment: "_you can serve only JSP or Servlets_", no, you can serve any content with a servlet container

Comment: My mistake. I was talking in a Java context. @PeterMmm